# Is there a workaround for parsing a certificate with explicit curve params?

Tags: go, openssl, cryptography, x509, asn.1

I have a certificate that I need to parse and verify in Go but parsing fails at `x509.ParseCertificate` with `x509: invalid ECDSA parameters` error. Here's [a playground snippet](https://go.dev/play/p/MG5Yg6DwN7n).

I've found these two issues in Go, which seemed related:

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21502
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23591

Turns out, x509 certificates must have a named curve specified in the Algorithm Identifier section, and that's exactly where parsing was failing.

I inspected the certificate, and indeed, it has explicit curve params specified instead of a named curve. [Pastebin link with ASN.1 description](https://pastebin.com/kXy3TuCD).

OpenSSL seems to have no problems parsing this certificate using `openssl x509 -noout -text -in` so in that sense the certificate seems to be valid.

I've tried to parse the certificate using [spacemonkeygo/openssl package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl#LoadCertificateFromPEM) and it succeeds but it doesn't look like I can use `Certificate` from this package in Go's standard `x509` package easily.

Are there any quick workarounds around the problem without having to use OpenSSL or forking Go's x509?

Please note that I used an example certificate in the playground and ASN.1 decoding but I didn't generate the original certificate I need to parse and cannot ask the issuer to do it differently.

Comment: For background, current PKIX = rfc5480 in 2009 requires named form, but rfc3279 in 2002 allowed the explicit form from X9.62/63 in 1998 (and SEC1v1 in 2000) which OpenSSL (already) implemented. X.509 itself only provides the SubjectPublicKeyInfo 'hole' and doesn't specify its contents. That said, I can't help with Go :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at the source code for go x509, and it looks distinctly like hand cut code, rather than code that's been machine generated from whatever asn1 schema files that the various standards for certificates use.

Which, unfortunately, means that with out-of-the-github Go, it'd be a fair piece of work to retrofit the old standards into Go's x509 implementation.

An alternative would be to get the asn.1 schemas for the x509 flavour that you want (I'm *assuming* that they exist!), and use the Objective System's [ASN1C](https://obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/asn1c_golang.php) (costs money) which can output Go source code. That way it'd be trivial to get a parser for any schema defined certificate format you wish (or indeed, any other ASN1 PDU in any encoding).

One of the unfortunate things I think is that Google's official serialiser is GPB which, fine (if limited) though it is, means that they're less focused on implementing good tools in Google languages for other, pre-existing serialisers such as ASN1.